# Mark an entity that's supposed to be handled differently from other entities

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, interface

I have an action I want to handle in two different ways by the types I get as a parameter.

Those types are the same as other types I'm supposed to handle differently.
They derives from the same interface and the same abstract class.

The method that decide what action to do , get Type as parameter.

Do you have an idea how to make it unique from the other types and know when to handle it one way and when to handle it second way?

I thought of adding property to the classes of the "unique" types and by `type.GetProperty("UniqueProp")` know if it is unique or not.
But i feel there has to be a better and faster way of doing it. It has to be efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how exactly did you set up your type handling class but suppose you have something similar to the following.

You said that both your classes derive from the same interface. You could then have an *IWork* interface for both types of classes.

```
interface IWork { }
```

Then you could create a custom attribute  which you will use to decorate classes that you know are special cases and you want to handle differently.

```
class SpecialAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Now you can define classes which will serve for either special or standard cases. You decorate the *SpecialClass* with the *SpecialAttribute* attribute.

```
[Special]
class SpecialClass : IWork { }

class StandardClass : IWork { }
```

And you also said that your type handling class receives types as its parameters. If that is so, you can then check if a type you passed to it is decorated with a *SpecialAttribute*, like so.

```
class HandleTypes
{
    public HandleTypes(Type type)
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes<SpecialAttribute>().Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Special case...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Standard case...");
        }
    }
}
```

You can test this setup in the following way.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    { 
        var standard = new StandardClass();
        var special = new SpecialClass();

        new HandleTypes(standard.GetType());
        new HandleTypes(special.GetType());

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I think it will be better then mark it with a propery.